# How to optimize image resolution using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm making a chessboard UI and I am not satisfied with it's resolution so I thought of optimizing its resolution.

This is my code so far:

```
function optimizeResolution(element) {
    var img = new Image();
    var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>')[0];


    img.onload = () => {
        canvas.width = '128px';
        canvas.height = '128px';
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(element[0], 0, 0, 128, 128);
    };


    img.src = element.attr('src');
    element.attr('src', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
}
```

The problem is that the canvas not drawing anything.

Comment: You never put anything to `element[0]`, maybe there should be `img` instead?

Comment: I think it will return the img element as DOM. I pass the img on that function as the jquery object.

Comment: But in that case `element.attr('src', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));` doesn't make sense, it reads an empty canvas to the image, and then you draw that back to the canvas after the new image has been loaded. And what's the use of the newly-created image then? It's not used at all, if you're not going to draw it to the canvas.